# Does ArcGIS online allow the use of ArcMap print templates?

Tags: arcgis-online, printing

The ArcGIS Server help page [Publishing additional services for printing](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/get-started/windows/tutorial-publishing-additional-services-for-printing.htm) shows how to publish an MXD as a print template:

> Navigate to Toolboxes > System Toolboxes > Server Tools > Printing.
>   Double-click the Export Web Map tool. Click Geoprocessing > Results to
>   display the Results window. Right-click the ExportWebMap result and
>   click Share As > Geoprocessing Service.

These instructions seem to apply to ArcGIS Server only. How can I use a print template, derived from an MXD, within **ArcGIS Online**?

(The question [Setting up ArcGIS Print service for ArcGIS Online account?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99915/setting-up-arcgis-print-service-for-arcgis-online-account) shows that ArcGIS Online supports a print service, but doesn't confirm that ArcGIS Online supports a custom template derived from ArcMap.)

Comment: as w/ custom geocoding, network analyst and geoprocessing services, ArcGIS Server is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot publish a hosted print service to ArcGIS Online. The print service has to be coming from an ArcGIS Server.

Russ

Comment: Are there any updates for this in 2018. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/configure-services.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5351FB676EEC43EF86595F978C908A3F